# adjust $\cdot$ in math expression

Tags: math-mode

I would like to obtain a better expression of this

```
$$
Au(\cdot)=\nabla_{(\cdot)}\left{\frac{\cdot}{|\cdot|^{3}}\,1_{B(0,r)}(\cdot)\right}.
$$
```

where `$\cdot$` refer to a variable `$x$`. More precisely, I want to place the `$\cdot$` just in the middle in the `\frac` command and adjust properly the size of the parenthesis in all `$(\cdot)$`.

Comment: To obtain curly braces, you need to type `\{` and `\}` rather than `{` and `}`. The latter are "special-function" characters in TeX, as they are used to start and end "groups" (chunks of code, if you will). The characters need to be "escaped" with a backslash, `\`, in order to generate curly braces.

Comment: It is not clear what you wish. For me the expression looks nice. Do you want a smaller parenthesis.?

Comment: I already used ${\small (}$ and ${\small )}$. I think it is much better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually define a `\blank` command for signposts in math expressions:

```
\newcommand{\blank}{{-}}
```

(the additional braces makes the symbol behave like a letter and not an operation symbol). You can adapt it to your liking:

```
\newcommand{\blank}{{\,\cdot\,}}
```

because some space should be added, in this case.

Here's the example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\blank}{{\,\cdot\,}}

\begin{document}
\[
\mathit{Au}(\blank)=
  \nabla_{(\blank)}
  \left\{ \frac{\blank}{\lvert\blank\rvert^{3}}\,
  1_{B(0,r)}(\blank) \right\}.
\]
\[
\mathit{Au}(\blank)=
  \nabla_{(\blank)}
  \left\{ \frac{\blank\hphantom{^{3}}}{\lvert\blank\rvert^{3}}\,
  1_{B(0,r)}(\blank) \right\}.
\]
\end{document}
```

In the second version, the dot is moved left by adding a phantom; I'm not sure it's really wanted.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

When you write that "I want to place the `\cdot` just in the middle in the `\frac` command", I assume you're referring to the expression in the denominator. (The `\cdot` in the numerator is already centered.) Centering the denominator term on the `\cdot` part may be achieved, e.g., by creating a "phantom" superscript term to the left of the first vertical bar. In the code below, I've further replaced `\left{` and `\right}` with `\left\{` and `\right\}` in order to generate auto-sized curly braces.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
Au(\cdot)=\nabla_{(\cdot)} \left\{ \frac{\cdot}{\phantom{{}^{3}}|\cdot|^{3}}\,
    1_{B(0,r)}(\cdot) \right\}.
\]
\end{document}
```

Incidentally, use of the `$$` displaymath switch is *heavily deprecated* in LaTeX. (See the discussion at [Why is `\[  \]` preferable to `$$ ... $$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001) for an in-depth examination of this issue.) In LaTeX documents, it's much better to use `\[` and `\]` to initiate and terminate displaymath mode, as is done in the example code above.